# redux Async Action Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: asynchronous, redux, redux-thunk

I used redux thunkMiddle to implement async action, but it was error when I send Http request in actions, the err is :

```
VM711:3 Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
    at Object.performAction (<anonymous>:3:2312)
    at liftAction (<anonymous>:2:27846)
    at dispatch (<anonymous>:2:31884)
    at Object.dispatch (bundle.js:22661)
    at dispatch (<anonymous>:2:1620)
    at Object.submitForm (bundle.js:23120)
    at Form.submitForm (bundle.js:23168)
    at Object.ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback (bundle.js:4532)
    at executeDispatch (bundle.js:4332)
    at Object.executeDispatchesInOrder (bundle.js:4355)
```

There is my code：

In my action,I use superagent to send  request,my code like this:

```
import superagent from 'superagent'
import async from 'async'

export const onSubmitForm = userInfo => {
    async.waterfall([
        (done) => {
            superagent
                .post('/userInfo')
                .send(userInfo)
                .end((err, res) => {
                    done(err, res.body)
                });
        }
    ], (err, data) => {
        return (dispatch) => (dispatch(submitFormAction(data)))
    });
};

export const submitFormAction = data => {
    return {
        type: "USER_INFO",
        data
    }
};
```

And This is my entry file，I import thunkMiddle from redux :

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import reducer from './reducers/index';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import {App} from './containers/App';


const store = createStore(reducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)));

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

So,how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A thunk must return a function - some of your code-paths result in nothing being returned.

try altering your action by wrapping it in a function which you can return:

```
export const onSubmitForm = userInfo => {
    return function(dispatch) {
        async.waterfall([
            (done) => {
                superagent
                    .post('/userInfo')
                    .send(userInfo)
                    .end((err, res) => {
                        done(err, res.body)
                    });
            }
        ], (err, data) => {
            dispatch(submitFormAction(data))
        });
    }
};
```